# Element with pointer-event: none, but still observe clicks

Tags: javascript, css, typescript, vuejs3

I have a popup, and to detect if a user clicks outside the popup area I have a cover element that covers the entire screen behind the popup. But since the cover element is over every element except for the popup, is it impossible to scroll on the page when the popup is open.

I want it so that the cover element does not observe any events other than the click event, which is necessary to close the popup.

I am of course open to other solutions than pointer-events. I am using vue so I'm trying to avoid heavy DOM-manipulation .

Here is the cover component css:

```css
.cover {
    position: fixed;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;


    z-index: 10;
}
```

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan Sorry if I was unclear in my question. I already have the popup working and I can interact with it. But I still want to be able to scroll on the background element behind the cover element while it still serves as a clickable cover.

Comment: Dude, we can't help you until you add a code example where you can reproduce the error.

Comment: please add your html and js as well

Comment: There is no JS or html only a single <div> with the class "cover"? The cover element gets displayed when the popups is shown @Apodemus.

Comment: So where does `pointer-events: none` come from?

Comment: The only element on the page has `postion: fixed`,  so scrolling wouldn't be an issue since it's always at the same position.

Comment: How are you using Vue without JavaScript?

Comment: @Apodemus its pointer-event being added to the cover class, but as i said in my question it does not work, becuse i cannot use the cover element when it has the pointer-evevnt: none; style.

Comment: But it doesn't have `pointer-events: none`, nor can it get any `pointer-events`, because there is no JavaScript used. Either the `pointer-events` are already in the CSS or you add it with JS, but there is no JS.

Answer (score 0):

Based on what I could reproduce from your code, very little changes in the code are needed. `.cover` doesn't have `pointer-events: none` and as you pointed out, there is no JavaScript, so it can't get `pointer-events`.

With the addition of a new event listener you could remove the `.cover` from the DOM, but it does require JavaScript. There is no need to explicitly ignore other events, since keyboard events on divs don't realy do anything by default and scrolling is of no concern since the only element on the page has `position: fixed`.

```js
document.querySelector(".cover").addEventListener(
"click",
e => {e.target.remove()}
)
```

```css
.cover {
    position: fixed;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    z-index: 10;
}
```

```html
<div class="cover"></div>
```